# Asynchronous Visual Web Part without ASP Update Panel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-web-part, server, updatepanel

I want to create the Asynchronous Visual Web Part(Which is not affecting the page load) without using `ASP:UpdatePanel`. Any idea how to achieve this??

Comment: Simply use traditionnel Ajax approaches, with jQuery or else. Nothing different in the context of SP than with standard ASP.NET (or even general Web) development.

Comment: Thanks! Are you saying use jQuery instead of server side code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Update Panel, we can use jQuery Ajax with some REST API or web service to achieve it.

[SharePoint 2013: Working with REST API using jQuery Ajax](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31995.sharepoint-2013-working-with-rest-api-using-jquery-ajax.aspx)

Instead of visual web part, we can use add-in with app part using client side code to achieve it